# loadMore() is not being called on browser scroll in ngInfiniteScroll

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

I am trying to implement infinite scroll for my angularjs app. To get acquainted with the usage of [ngInfiniteScroll](https://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)

I am using same example given in their [demos](https://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demos.html)

page. It is not working for me,

**profile.ejs**:

```
    <script  src='../controllers/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script  src='../controllers/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script  src='../controllers/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js'></script>

    <!-- some other code -->

        <ul infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='1' >
           <div ng-repeat="item in images">Item number {{$index}}: {{$item}}</div>
        </ul>

<!-- some other code -->
```

**profileController.js**

```
$scope.images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

$scope.loadMore = function() {
    alert("called");
    var last = $scope.images[$scope.images.length - 1];
    for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
      $scope.images.push(last + i);
    }

  };
```

The `alert("called")` is not being called on browser scroll. Can anyone help me where I am wrong or how can I achieve infinite scroll?

Comment: You're probably missing something in your module and controller declaration, make sure you follow all the steps in this link: http://4dev.tech/2015/08/tutorial-implementing-infinite-scroll-with-angularjs-and-nginfinitescroll/

Answer (score 0):

How did you defined your angular module and controller ?

=> you must inject "infinite-scroll" dependecy in your module.
=> you must defined "infiniteScroll" controller in your module.

"loadmore" function had to be in the "infiniteScroll" controller.